# How to declare global methods/objects in Vuejs 2?

Tags: javascript, vuejs2

I have a `Vue` instance where I want to make accessible to all components some

- methods
- objects

I wrote this:

```
import mqtt from 'mqtt'

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  methods: {
    foo: function() {
      console.log("Hello Foo!");
    }
    mqtt: mqtt.connect('mqtt://server:8083')
  },
  render: h => h(App), 
  router
});
```

Unfortunately, in my components I cannot reach either `foo` nor `mqtt`.

```
<template>

</template>
<script>

export default {
  data() {
    return {};
  },
  mounted() {
    this.foo(); // Doesn't work
    this.mqtt.on('connect', () => {}) // Doesn't work
  }
}
</script>
```

What's wrong?

Comment: What is the function `toto`?

Comment: My mistake, it was `foo`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To distribute pure functions (without side effects) you can use mixins.

```
const mixin = {
    methods:{
        foo() {
            console.log('foo')
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can define the mixin in the vue instance:

```
new Vue({
    mixins: [mixin],
    // ...
})
```

This function can now be used in every component as if it where defined there.

Your mqtt connection is quite another story. You are sharing the result of `mqtt.connect`. This function does not return a function, so it cannot be shared via methods. Furthermore: This function creates state. A good way to share state is `Vuex`. With `Vuex` you can share state across multiple components and define mutations.

Define a store in `src/store/index.js`:

```
const store = new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    connected: false,
    result: null
  },
  mutations: {
    setMqtt (state, mqttResult) {
      state.connected = true
      state.result = mqttResult
    }
  }
})
```

Add it to your app:

```
import store from './store'

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  mixins: [mixin],
  store,
  // ....
})
```

Now you can access this store in each component, with:

```
this.$store.state.connected
this.$store.state.result
```

The access should only be done in functions that are defined in `computed`. As soon as any change occurs in the state, all functions defined in computed are evaluated again.

Now you can fetch the data in your main file and commit the result:

```
mqtt.connect('mqtt://server:8083').on('connect', (someData) => {
    store.commit('setMqtt', someData)
})
```

Links to the official docs:

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/mixins.html

https://vuex.vuejs.org/

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am starting the implementation but still, I am far away from using this `mounted() {this.foo(); }` in my components.

Comment: I guess the solution would be to add the mixins to every components I use or, better, inherit from a component that implements this mixins. Is that correct?

Comment: You can inject it as a global mixin: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/mixins.html#Global-Mixin

Comment: Right, but I cannot call the methods from my global mixins into my sub-components. Remember I would like to do `mounted() {this.foo(); }` from any component of my application.

Comment: Why not? This should be possible. Also, you could define `mounted` in the mixin.

Comment: @nowox When you declare you functions under `methods` they will be mixed in and should be callable, like `this.foo()`. Have you tried that?